# How can i give a white box like broder around my ag-grid scrollbar?

Tags: css, reactjs, scrollbar, ag-grid

I am working with Ag-grid for react JavaScript. I have been provided with a wire frame which changes the default scroll bar of the Ag-grid . My aim is to reproduce the same for my UI .

I have tried to introduce some css changes using webkit scrollbar. The code has been written as a styled component . My problem is that every time I try to give some width or height to the scrollbar , the track and the thumb of the scroll bar takes up the entire width . The code has been provided below .

```css
.ag-theme-fresh .ag-root{
        
        min-height: 200px;
        border: ${props => props.showBorder === true ? "1px solid #efefef" : "0px"};
    }
.ag-theme-fresh .ag-header{
    background-image: none;    
    font-family: "Frutiger";
    border-bottom: none;
    color:#646464;
    height:50px;
    min-height:50px;
}
.ag-theme-fresh .ag-header-row,.ag-theme-fresh .ag-pivot-off{
    height: 50px !important;
    min-height: 50px !important;
}


.ag-theme-fresh .ag-header-cell, .ag-theme-fresh .ag-ltr .ag-cell{
    border:none;
}
.ag-theme-fresh .ag-header-cell{
   
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px
    height: auto;
}
.ag-theme-fresh .ag-cell{
    line-height: 50px;
}
.ag-theme-fresh .ag-row-odd{
    background-color:white;
}

.ag-theme-fresh .ag-row-even{
    background-color:#eeeeee;
}
.ag-root ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    box-shadow: -5px 3px 6px 0 rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.16);
    background-color: #ffffff;
width:50 px;
height:900px;
   

}   

.ag-root :: -webkit-scrollbar-track {
    width:7px !important;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 px grey; 
    border-radius: 10px;
    background:#ededed;
    height:856px;
}  

.ag-root :: -webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #cccccc;
    width:7px !important;
    height:785px; 
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

The problem is that I have tried to give some width and height to the scrollbar property to create a box like structure , however the scroll bar takes up the entire width . How should I solve this problem ?

The images depicting the issue that I am facing are given below . The first image depicts the wireframe and the second image depicts the result that I got.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Image for the wireframe]

[image: My scrollbar]

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet please

Comment: That would be a bit difficult since the code is way too large for that . However , you can copy paste my snippet in a .scss file and import it in the file for the ag-grid .That should give you a working example.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to remove the bar at all so I did that (in SCSS) :

```
    .body-editor{
     height: fit-content ;
     margin-top:-5px;
     overflow: auto;
     **&::-webkit-scrollbar{width: 0px !important;}**
}
```

Try to use ::-webkit-scrollbar{} ?

Comment: Please check the code that I have provided , for a better understanding of my situation.